# Iterator loop does not count the last item

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

Assuming the linked list is defined this way:

```
template <typename Object>
struct Node{
    Object data;
    Node *prev;
    Node *next;

    Node(const Object & d = Object(), Node *p = NULL, Node *n = NULL)
    : data(d), prev(p),next(n){}
};

template <typename Object>
class List
{
public:
   iterator begin(){return iterator(head->next);}
   iterator end(){return iterator(tail);}
....
private:
   Node *head=nullptr;
   Node *tail=nullptr;
...
```

The iterators:

```
class iterator
{
public:
    iterator():current(NULL){}
    Object & operator*(){return retrieve();}
    iterator & operator++()
    {
        current = current->next;
        return *this;
    }
    ....
private:
    Node *current;
    ...
```

There is a problem in this code.

```
for(iterator<Object> itr = list.begin(); itr != list.end(); itr++ )
    std::cout<<(*itr)->name;
```

This loop counts until the one item member before the last one. So, the last member of this list is not  counted in this loop. How to fix it?

Comment: `template <typename Object>` before `struct Node`? or what is `Object`?

Comment: @mnciitbhu I avoided putting the whole code. I just put the necessary code. The problem is from list and iterator. Object can be any class. it does not matter.

Comment: `iterator begin(){return iterator(head->next);` looks wrong (Are head and tail holding valid data? Are these sentinel nodes?)

Comment: What is exactly for you the last member ? The nullptr or the one before it ?

Comment: @perencia `tail` is pointing to the actual last member. I dont use sentinel nodes and `tail->next` is nullptr.

Comment: @zahmati `I just put the necessary code`  And we still have questions.  Better you had posted more than what you thought was necessary.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the linked list has problem. no matter what you put in it.

Comment: @zahmati `tail is pointing to the actual last member.`  So of course you won't get to the last entry, because that is what you coded.  The `end` iterator is the tail, and your loop says "keep going until you get to the tail".  Maybe rethink your design a bit?

Comment: In fact, as the code is, you could use as the for condition it != somerandomvalue. Maybe you could implement the != operator on the iterator and check for the nullptr on data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your "end" iterator is a pointer to the last element. That's wrong.

It's supposed to be ["one past" the last element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13066884/560648).

Comment: So should end be nullptr?