# erasing an element of a static member of class list

Tags: c++

I have the following class. It has a static member `_list` to be shared by all instances of the class, which will be created within `Class_f()`. I want to use the erase function in order to erase say the last element of `_list`.

```
class myClass 
{
    private:
        static list<int> _list;
    public:
        //constructors,destructors
        void Class_f();
}

list<int> myCLass::_list;

void myClass::Class_f() 
{
    //..some code
    list<int>::iterator it1;
    it1=_list.end (); //erase for instance the last element _list
    it1=_list.erase(it1);
    //more code
}
```

However when compiling it outputs me an error with the message "list iterator not incrementable". Why is it giving me this error? In addition, why can't I use something simpler like `_list.erase(_list.end())` so as to avoid creating an iterator.

Comment: `_list.rbegin()` should be the last element in the list.

Answer (score 5):

`_list.end()` is not an iterator to the last element. It is the one-past-the-end iterator. You can't really do anything with it. [C++'s iterator ranges are half-open](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13066884/560648).

However, if you're really getting a *compiler* error, then something is wrong that you haven't shown us.

More likely you're seeing a debugger message from runtime, wherein the standard library implementation in debug mode has very kindly discovered your attempt to increment `_list.end()` (which would have undefined behaviour), which happens during the preparation of return value for `_list.erase(it1)` and told you not to be such a doofus. :)

Comment: sorry, I should have meant "debugger message". At any rate, the error comes precisely from accessing an element past the size of list. How can I access then the last element?

Comment: @SrIncerteza: Did you lose your internet access? You can simply read the documentation for `std::list` to find out. The other answers have told you which to use, also (though I prefer to leave a little something for you to discover on your own).

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, list.end() gives you a "iterator referring to the past-the-end element". So calling erase(list.end()) will not work.

Secondly, use list.pop_back() to delete the last element. 
[List.pop_back()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/pop_back/)

Answer (score 3):

With `_list.pop_back()` you can delete the last element, which is maybe more convenient than to use the `erase` function.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/pop_back/