# map.end() error "iterator not dereferenceable" c++

Tags: c++, dictionary

```
//Works    
cout << "map[0] value is " << doubleStatsMap.begin()->first<< endl;
//gives error
cout << "map[last value is " << doubleStatsMap.end()->first << endl;
```

Im simply trying to get the value of the last element of my map. It works correctly with
 "map.begin->first" 
but is giving "map/set iterator not dereferencable" for the
 "map.end()->first".
 It cant be empty as the map has a beginning thus it has an end. Everything I've read says this should work. Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Docs: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/end

Comment: Iterators form a half-open range... Please read the documentation on iterators again.

Comment: You're thinking of `back()`, which returns a reference to the last element.

Comment: *"Everything I've read says this should work."* You should either get better reading material or read the material more carefully.

Comment: `end()` is an iterator to *beyond last element* - you cannot dereference it; it does not point to a valid element.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to get anything from the *end* iterator causes undefined behavior.

To get the last item, you can use `std::map::rbegin()`.

```
// cout << "map[last value is " << doubleStatsMap.end()->first << endl;
cout << "map[last value is " << doubleStatsMap.rbegin()->first << endl;
```

Comment: THANK YOU. I don't care if I get downvoted for asking this. I saw examples of end and its been driving me crazy.

Comment: so what is the point of having a "first" and "second" function attached to end(). further, what is the point of even having a [poorly named] end function anyway as maps cannot be referenced like arrays by index anyway?

Comment: @Mason, good questions. The answers to them are long and not appropriate in a SO comment.

Comment: @Mason `end` is not "poorly named" - read up on half-open ranges. Also, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066884/what-is-half-open-range-and-off-the-end-value (especially the accepted answer).