# Sorting part of vector (in place)

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, stl, range

I could not understand why below piece of code is not sorting first two elements of vector :

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = {2,1,3,1,2};
    std::sort(v.begin(),v.begin()+1);
    for(auto elem:v)
    {
      std::cout<<elem<<std::endl;
    }
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::sort` (and all standard library algorithms) expects a *half-open* range. The end iterator is a one-past end indicator (the open part). So `[it, it + 1)` is a range of just one element. In your case, it's just the first vector element.

And well, a one element range is already sorted.

Answer (score 3):

This range `v.begin(),v.begin()+1` that can be mathematically written like `[v.begin(), v.begin() + 1 )` contains only one element `v[0]` that is equal to `2`. If you want to sort a range of 2 elements then you should write

```
std::sort( v.begin(), std::next( v.begin(), 2 ) );
```

that is equivalent to

```
std;:sort( v.begin(), v.begin() + 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sorts the elements in the range [first, last)
```

from [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

In case you are not familiar with the notation, `)` means `last` is not included, you can find more information about that in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13066884/612920).

Comment: Just curious about the term "RTMF", care to explain?

Answer (score 1):

In order to sort first n elements you must indicate you call as follows:

```
sort(V.begin(), V.begin() + n);
```

Thus for 2 elements you must call:

```
 sort(V.begin(), V.begin() + 2);
```

This is because all STL algorithms takes open range [first, last).