# Slice declarations like [0:2]

Tags: go, slice

I don't understand slice declarations in Go.

For, me a declaration for the first and second element of an array must be 0:1.
But it is 0:2. Why? How should I read this, from zero to 2 minus 1 (all the time)?

```
var slice = array[0:2]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slice bounds are [half open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066884/what-is-half-open-range-and-off-the-end-value), this is very standard for many programming languages. One advantage is that it makes the length of the range apparent (2-0=2). Specifically, it's common to do this:

```
s[start:start+len]
```

And it's obvious that this selects `len` elements from the slice, starting with `start`. If the range would be fully closed (both bounds included), there would have to be a lot of `-1`s in code to deal with slicing and subslicing.

It works similarly in C++ ranges and Python, etc. Here's some reasoning from a [C++ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9963438/8206), attributed to Dijkstra:

- You want the size of the range to be a simple difference end − begin;
- including the lower bound is more "natural" when sequences degenerate to empty ones, and also because the alternative (excluding the lower bound) would require the existence of a "one-before-the-beginning" sentinel value.

Answer (score 1):

> A slice is formed by specifying two indices, a low and high bound,
>   separated by a colon:
>
> `a[low : high]`
>
> This selects a half-open range which includes the first
>   element, but excludes the last one.

This is from Golang's page on slices https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7

Comment: thank you, I did not understand the idea behind a "half-open range". havent seen this in php and c before...

Comment: @ABSimon: C does the same with arrays. `int a[10]` creates elements 0-9.

Comment: @ZanLynx I think that's because of the length and not half - openness